# Are there any open-source references for the web2py remote-procedure-calls?

Tags: python, rpc, web2py

Are there any open-source references for the [web2py](http://web2py.com) [remote procedure calls](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09#Remote-Procedure-Calls) (i.e. @service.run) to get information from and post it to a table in the database?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you post to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups&pli=1#!forum/web2py) with some more details, someone will probably be able to offer help.

Comment: I don't think this actually has anything to do with App Engine, does it?

Comment: I was going to deploy to GAE, but yeah, maybe the tag was wrong. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

@service.run is not very useful it is more for testing before you move on to xmlrpc or soap or jsonrpc than anything else. You should use a restful interface for what you asked. For example:

```
db.define_table('mytable,Field('name'))

@request.restful()
def callme():
    def GET(id):
        return db.mytable(id)
    def POST(name):
        return db.mytable.insert(name=name)
    return locals()
```